# Android Vitamio 4.2 update 5.0 crash

Tags: android, vitamio

I updated Vitamio 4.2.2 to 5.0.0 as Google requested because of security issues in developer console. But with the same codes. Only changed Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext()); There is not error. Application was installed. But video not playing. How can i do for this?

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static String ShowTV = "http://mn-i.mncdn.com/showtv_ios/smil:showtv.smil/playlist.m3u8";";
private TextView tvLoader;
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    else
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    tvLoader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoader);
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}


public void playVideo() {
    doCleanUp();
    try {

        // Create a new media player and set the listeners
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(ShowTv);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");

}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    tvLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    playVideo();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void doCleanUp() {
    tvLoader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoader);
    tvLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

Comment: please show us some code related to your problem. without it helping you is very difficutl

Comment: i added code can u look

Comment: please add crash log/ stack trace